# How to pass values from controller to view in grails 3

Tags: groovy, grails3

In the controller I have which is having two values say `name` and `amount`.

In the controller I wrote

```
def d=[name:amount]
render (view: "/user.gsp", model: [user: d])
```

and in the view

```
${user}
```

This is giving the output as `{name=amount}`. But I want something like "My name and my amount".

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

try this...

in controller

```
def create={           
        def customer = Customer.findAllByCif(cif)
        def getDOnumber= '(AUTO)'
//do anything and pass to view like this.


        [paramsCustomerCallat: customer, paramsparamsCustomerCallatView: getDOnumber]
    }
```

then you receive the params like this.

```
 <g:textField name="invoiceNo" value="${getDOnumber}" class="form-control" />
```

if you want to call that `key` and `value` in a record, i suggest you to change your code like this..

```
def d=[keyname:"name", keyamount:"myamount"]
render (view: "/user.gsp", model: [user: d])
```

then you can call  like this in view

```
${user.keyname+" - "+user.keyamount}
```